# Pause for loop every x minutes

Tags: python

How can I create a loop that sleeps a random amount of time every X minutes, where X is also a random duration of time?

I also want to be able to specify the upper and lower boundaries of the random durations of both times.

Comment: based on the amount of time, not the number of iterations?  Interesting, may I ask why?

Comment: I'm doing some scraping, but the site (reasonably) limits the number of requests per hour. I suppose I could also keep track of the iterations and have it sleep every y times. I thought sleeping after an amount of time that is random may make the scraper appear more human (make it appear as though "breaks" are being taken).

Comment: after coming up with a solution I must say it wasn't very hard, did you actually try to do this before asking someone else to write the code for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like **this**:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

# Randomly select a time between 20 to 30 minutes
# before sleeping.
random_time_duration = random.randint(1200,1800)

# Randomly sleep between 60 to 120 seconds.
sleep_duration = random.randint(60,120)

# This is the start time of of loop used to track
# how much time has passed.
old_time = datetime.now()

while True:
  # Check if the randomly selected duration has
  # passed before running your code block.
  if (datetime.now()-old_time).total_seconds() > random_time_duration:
    sleep(sleep_duration)

    # Reset all the time variables so the loop works
    # again.
    random_time_duration = random.randint(1200,1800)
    sleep_duration = random.randint(60,120)
    old_time = datetime.now()

  else:
    # Put your code in here.
    pass
```

Comment: `time.time()` doesn't reflect the progression of time through midnight

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware of that, thanks! I just changed it to use datetime instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
sleep_time = 50 #time to sleep in seconds
difference = 30
sleep_time = random.randint(sleep_time-difference, sleep_time+difference)
sleep_every = 10 #ammount of time to wait before sleeping in minutes
cur_time = time.time()

while True: #change to your for loop
    if time.time() - cur_time >= sleep_time * 60:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        cur_time = time.time()
    else:
        #your code here
        print time.time() - cur_time
```

can obviously be adapted to a function but this works perfectly

Comment: `time.time()` gives a lower value right after midnight so this wouldn't work over nght, also using `cur_time` to represent the last time it slept probably isn't the best choice of variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import datetime
import time
import random

sleep_duration = 60

previous_sleep = datetime.datetime.now()

random_offset = random.randint(-5, 5)

while(True):

    delta = (datetime.datetime.now() - previous_sleep).total_seconds()

    if delta < 60 * (20 + random_offset):
        # Do stuff
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    else:
        previous_sleep = datetime.datetime.now()
        random_offset = random.randint(-5, 5)
        time.sleep(sleep_duration)
```

This program would sleep for 60 seconds every 15-25 minutes, depending on the random offset computed.

Comment: only using the `.seconds` portion of the difference seems like a mistake, what if each iteration took longer then a minute?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen you're right, just modified to `total_seconds()`

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code using `datetime.now()` and `timedelta`s to calculate the next interval somewhat randomly, this has an advantage over using `time.time` or similar since that would fail at midnight since the date would also be important in that case:

```
import time
import random
import datetime

sleep_duration = 1 #seconds
min_sleep_interval = max_sleep_interval = 3 #in seconds

_TIME_TO_SLEEP = datetime.datetime.now()
def maybe_sleep():
    #using a singleton class you could avoind using globals
    global _TIME_TO_SLEEP
    if datetime.datetime.now()>= _TIME_TO_SLEEP:
        time.sleep(sleep_duration)
        seconds_to_wait = random.randint(min_sleep_interval, max_sleep_interval)
        next_delay = datetime.timedelta(seconds= seconds_to_wait)
        _TIME_TO_SLEEP = datetime.datetime.now() + next_delay
```

Then just call `maybe_sleep()` every iteration and adjust the constants to your liking (maybe make them less constant ;)

As a demo:

```
for i in range(10000):
    maybe_sleep()
    print(i)
```